# Cant stop the flow of a loop | Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Im trying return an int that count the last Zeros of an int, but I can´t to stop the flow of the loop when it finds something that is not zero. whats wrong?

```
const endZeros = (value) => {
  const stringValue = `${value}`
  const arrValue = stringValue.split("").reverse()
  let total = 0;
  arrValue.map(el => {
    if (el === "0") {
      total = total + 1
    } else {
      return // I check return false too (and true, and all! --> desesperation)
    }
  })
  return total;
}

endZeros(100100)
```

Thank You, everyone ❤️

Comment: Use `for-loop` with break instead of `.map`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Can you share an input array to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple regexp?

```js
const lastZeros = num => { const zeros = String(num).match(/0+$/); return zeros ? zeros[0].length : 0 };

console.log(lastZeros(100100))
console.log(lastZeros(111111))
console.log(lastZeros(101000))
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed!,  the truth is that I have not thought about doing it with regex, but there is something that catches my attention:

the result of
     `const zeros = String(num).match(/0+$/);`
its something like this
     `['0', index: 5, input: '201010', groups: undefined] `
according to `typeof` an object (array)

But where does that come from? Where can I find more information about that response? very very very thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.... You are talking about the "match" object of `String(num).match(/0+$/)`

Comment: Sorry, I will try to explain me better, but I understand its dificult because we think in different way, I mean that I dont understand this result: `['0', index: 5, input: '201010', groups: undefined]`--> match() return this array always?

Comment: Yes: it is looking for '0', found the last one in position 5, the input was 201010 and there were no (groups) defined - The assigned toString is the match. I never debug a match object. I do destruct it if I use groups